# how to use regex with user input variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting an array of objects using JSON and then my goal is to let the user search for a specific login. For this I want them to be able to type a letter and check each object login, if the letter is contained I want to display it. 
In order to achieve this I worked on the following code:

```
var i;
var out="";
var exp=/d/g;
var result = " ";
for(i=0;i<users.length;i++){
   result= exp.test(users[i].login);
   if(result){
   out+= users[i].login+ " ";
    }

 }
```

It works fine if I write the regex (in this case d) but once I try putting a variable inside the regex it wont work. How do I create a regex that will take the users input and work with the test function to perform the same task? Or idk if there is a better/more elegant solution for this. I know there are different regex questions already but I didn't find one that helped me.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you sure you want a regex when what you've described sounds more like `if( users[i].login.indexOf(userInput) > -1)`

Comment: `var variable = 'd'; new RegExp(variable, 'g');` (Putting this as a *comment,* because I believe Niet has provided the *answer*)

Comment: I believe you are correct Niet. I am new to JavaScript and found the indexOf but I was unsure if I could use it so I went with the approach of regex. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Cool. @NiettheDarkAbsol could you post your answer before someone else steals it?

Comment: Niet, could you post your comment as an answer? I want to credit you with the answer and mark the question as answered... can't do it from the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

You're testing a literal string - that string is passed in by the user but it's still literal, not a regex.

So you should try:

```
if( users[i].login.indexOf(userInput) > -1)
```

This will pass if the given input is in the searched string.